# How do I access the date from an rShiny dateInput?

Tags: shiny

I am trying to write an input page that takes the date of a section's last training, then calculates the currency of that training (how many days since), but I seem to be having a problem accessing the date from the `dateInput` element. I'm currently just trying to get it to print, but it is eluding me. Is there something I'm missing, or how can I get this to work? I've commented out the code to (hopefully) calculate the date gap, as I haven't had a date to work through that just yet. If you see an issue there, I'd appreciate that pointer as well.

Thank you!

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h3("Section Training"),
  dateInput("section_Last_Training", 
            "When was your last training course?",
            daysofweekdisabled = c(0, 6),
            max = Sys.Date()
            ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  section_Last_Training <- reactive({
    # dateGap = as.character(difftime(Sys.time(), input$section_Last_Training, units = "days"))
    print(input$section_Last_Training)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, just make sure the last value in `reactive` is the value you want to assign to the `reactive`. You can do print, but do it before your gap calculation. Another thing is `reactive` is "lazily" evaluated. It means if there is no downstream reactivity requires it, it will not be calculated. So you need to add some events that require this `reactive` to make it work. See the code below.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$h3("Section Training"),
    dateInput("section_Last_Training", 
              "When was your last training course?",
              daysofweekdisabled = c(0, 6),
              max = Sys.Date()
    ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    section_Last_Training <- reactive({
        print(input$section_Last_Training)
        as.character(difftime(Sys.time(), input$section_Last_Training, units = "days"))
    })
    observe(print(section_Last_Training()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I am fairly new to shiny, so I didn't think about using the observe outside of the reactive to run on it, but that makes perfect sense and, more importantly, it works! Thank you very much!!!